# Getting Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException in Plot3DPanel

Tags: java, swing, plot, awt

I am continuously getting the following error when using Plot3DPanel

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.math.plot.render.Projection.screenProjection(Unknown Source)
            at org.math.plot.render.AWTDrawer.drawLine(Unknown Source)
            at org.math.plot.plotObjects.Line.plot(Unknown Source)
            at org.math.plot.plotObjects.Axis.plot(Unknown Source)
            at org.math.plot.plotObjects.BasePlot.plot(Unknown Source)
            at org.math.plot.canvas.PlotCanvas.paint(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

When I call `removeAllPlots();` method in a loop and try to refresh the panel continuously, I get the errors. However, if I use a new `JFrame` for each iteration, there is no error, but multiple windows.

This is my loop:

```
if(unlocalizedPlanes.size() > 0)
            {
                buildPlaneAdjacents();
                planeLocalized(seed);
                seedSensors.addAll(seed.getSensors());
                //System.out.println("Seed plane found");

            }

            Set<Plane> ext = new TreeSet<>();
            System.out.println("Localizing planes");
            do
            {
                plot();
                ext.clear();
                for(Plane p : recentlyLocalized)
                    ext.addAll(p.findLocalizableAdjacents());
                localizedPlanes.addAll(recentlyLocalized);
                recentlyLocalized.clear();
                planesLocalized(ext);
                System.out.println(ext.size() + " planes localized");

            }
            while(ext.size() > 0);
            localizedPlanes.addAll(recentlyLocalized);
```

And this is my `plot()` function:

```
public void plot()
    {

        int i=0;
        double[] xu = new double[unlocalizedSensors.size()+1];
        double[] yu = new double[unlocalizedSensors.size()+1];
        double[] zu = new double[unlocalizedSensors.size()+1];
        double[] xl = new double[localizedSensors.size()+1];
        double[] yl = new double[localizedSensors.size()+1];
        double[] zl = new double[localizedSensors.size()+1];
        double[] xs = new double[seedSensors.size()+1];
        double[] ys = new double[seedSensors.size()+1];
        double[] zs = new double[seedSensors.size()+1];



        xs[0] = 0;
        ys[0] = 0;
        zs[0] = 0;
        xl[0] = 0;
        yl[0] = 0;
        zl[0] = 0;
        xu[0] = 0;
        yu[0] = 0;
        zu[0] = 0;
        for(Sensor s : seedSensors)
        {
            xs[i] = s.getLocation().x;
            ys[i] = s.getLocation().y;
            zs[i] = s.getLocation().z;
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        for(Sensor s : unlocalizedSensors)
        {
            xu[i] = s.getLocation().x;
            yu[i] = s.getLocation().y;
            zu[i] = s.getLocation().z;
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        for(Sensor s : localizedSensors)
        {
            xl[i] = s.getLocation().x;
            yl[i] = s.getLocation().y;
            zl[i] = s.getLocation().z;
            i++;
        }

        plotXYZ.addScatterPlot("Localized", Color.GREEN, xl, yl, zl);

        plotXYZ.addScatterPlot("Unlocalized", Color.RED, xu, yu, zu);


        plotXYZ.addScatterPlot("Seed", Color.BLUE, xs, ys, zs);


        plotXYZ.setFixedBounds(0, 0, length);
        plotXYZ.setFixedBounds(1, 0, width);
        plotXYZ.setFixedBounds(2, 0, height);


        plotXYZ.removeAllPlots();

    }
```

Comment: The stack trace indicates the exception is throw at `org.math.plot.render.Projection.screenProjection` at `org.math.plot.render.AWTDrawer.drawLine` but I don't see those in the code you've included. Those are probably the methods we need to see first here. (Indicate the line that throws if possible. That is the first clue.)

Comment: I use neither of the methods. Maybe JMathPlot is using it I don't know.

Comment: Well what this sounds like is a classic [memory consistency error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) due to [updating the GUI off the EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (which it seems like you're doing). These types of errors are very difficult to pinpoint, probably the `plotXYZ` object you are interacting with does not see some mutation when it gets repainted on the EDT. Otherwise, if all of this is done on the EDT, then it must be a plain old NPE where some object you are working with is null.

Comment: @Radiodef I also have this anomaly:
Blue and SOME of the green points remain the same after the first iteration (they all need to turn red), but afterwards the plotting is normal. Or is this something different?

Comment: That sounds like the same thing: memory inconsistency. You probably need to use synchronized, a lock, invokeLater/invokeAndWait, etc. The stuff happening in `paint` is seeing stale values.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by making my class `Runnable` and using `SwingUtils.invokeLater()` function. This way, the repainting sync error won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

This was a difficult one to resolve. I made the execute function run, removed the throws clause, and made the GradientDescent class implement Runnable. This pertains to the following tutorial: http://rodrigoaraujo.me/articles/2015-01/Making-Your-Machine-Think-Learn-And-Predict-Gradient-Descent-Algorithm-in-Java .